# PHP5 __construct not called, no errors

Tags: php, constructor, php-5.3

All of a sudden, a script that was working fine for quite some time has stopped, with no error. I've pinned it down to the __contruct method but cannot understand why it's happening. Simplified version of the code....

```
<?php
class ex1 {
    protected $dbh;
    function __construct(){
        $this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'user', 'pw', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
    }
}
?>


<?php
include('ex1.class.php');
class ex2 extends ex1 {
    somefunc(){
        is_object($this->dbh); // = FALSE
    }
}
?>
```

The PDO constructor works on its own, in fact nothing I put in the ex1 constructor seems to run and no errors in the logs (set to E_ALL & E_STRICT).

Any ideas?

Comment: class `ex1()` isn't instantiated by its child `ex2()`, nor has a construct that calls the parent, so `ex1()` constructor isn't called

Comment: If you're happy and you know it... syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, your `ex2` class has a constructor on it's own, you should call the parent one from it:

```
class ex2 extends ex1 {

    function __contruct() {
        /* ex2::__construct() code here */
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function somefunc() {
        is_object($this->dbh);
    }
}
```

Also you have a typo:

```
somefunc() {}
```

should be:

```
function somefunc() {}
```

Comment: An empty constructor that just calls the parent constructor is redundant. If the constructor is not overridden, then the parent constructor is called anyway

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem you are right. But we dont know if he has constructor in the ex2 class because this is "simplified version" of his code

Comment: @phantom: Just read that bit after commenting here. You're right, looks like the constructor is being overridden

Comment: parent::__construct(); fixed it, thanks all :) odd how it was working for so long without it though!

Answer (score 4):

The simple rules of inheritance (in terms of constructors) are as follows:

- If the child class does not have its own constructor, then the parent constructor is used
- If the child class *does* have its own constructor, the parent constructor must be called explicitly
- The contract between the parent and child class applies to the constructor, too

Basically, that means that, applied to your code, the parent constructor *should* be called automatically. You say the constructor is not being called, so you probably defined a constructor in the child class, in which case, simple add this statement:

```
parent::__construct();
```

A couple of examples

```
class Foo
{
    protected $val = null;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->val = 123;
    }
}
class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function test()
    {
        return $this->val;
    }
}
$b = new Bar();
echo $b->test();
```

This will echo `123`, because `Foo::__construct()` is called automatically. However, if we change `Bar` a bit, then the behaviour changes:

```
class Bar extends Foo
{
    protected $another = null;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->another = __METHOD__;
    }
    public function test()
    {
        return $this->val;
    }
}
$b = new Bar();
var_dump($b->test());//null
```

So the `val` property isn't being set. A simple fix, though:

```
class Bar extends Foo
{
    protected $another = null;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->another = __METHOD__;
        parent::__construct();//call here, explicitly
    }
    public function test()
    {
        return $this->val;
    }
    public function getMethod()
    {
        return $this->another;
    }
}
$b = new Bar();
var_dump($b->test());//123
echo $b->getMethod();//echoes Bar::__construct
```

All in all, setting properties to an instance of `PDO` isn't considered the best of ideas. Check out *dependency injection*, google inversion of control and all those buzz-words.

An alternative approach would be to use lazy-loading getters:

```
class Foo
{
    $this->db = null;
    protected function getDb()
    {
        if ($this->db === null)
            $this->db = new PDO();//create when needed
        return $this->db;
    }
}
```

This way, the DB connection will be created at the last possible moment, when the code that relies on that connection calls the `getDb` method...